# Loop statement with two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I need to do a program where it will ask first name and then last name. the code should detect if the input is in lowercase letters, if not it will repeat to ask first name and last name.

here is what i did but it does not detect if the input is in lowercase

```
firstName = input(“Enter your First Name: “)
lastName = input(“Enter your Last Name: “)

fn = (firstName.islower())
ln = (lastName.islower())

while firstName != fn and lastName != lastName != ln:
     print (“Your First and Last name should be typed in lowercase letter”)
     firstName = input(“Enter your First Name: “)
     lastName = input(“Enter your Last Name: “)


print (“yey!”)
```

Comment: See [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), items number 12 and 13. You CANNOT force a user to enter their name in upper- or lower-case specifically. Capitalisation may be significant.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the code you posted has obvious syntax errors. Simply copy/paste the code *exactly;* don't use a word processor which replaces quotes with "typographers' quotes" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from some the silly logical error in the loop condition, your code is good. Here's a corrected version:

```
firstName = input("Enter your first name: ")
lastName = input("Enter your last name: ")

while not firstName.islower() or not lastName.islower():
     print("Your first and last name should be typed in lowercase letters")
     firstName = input("Enter your first name: ")
     lastName = input("Enter your last name: ")

print ("yey!")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code we check if both first and last name are in lowercase if not the user need to try again.
I hope is what you intend to.

```
first_name = ""
last_name = ""
while True:
    # Receive the first name and the last name from the user
    first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")
    last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")
    # check if the first name and the last name are in lower case if yes it exit otherwise print try again
    if first_name.islower() and last_name.islower():
        break
    print("Your first name and last name need to be in lowercase please try again")
print("yay!")
```

Actually in your first try you was really close to it.
I have made those changes:

- No need to do input out of the loop. is just duplicate the code, and make the input in one place make it easier :) .
- Need to check if the string is a lowercase inside the loop. and check it for every input you receive until you find a good one.

Comment: `input` always returns a string. The condition `first_name is not None` is always true. Why bother checking it?